# Is there a way to write a query that will combine rows according to set critera?

Tags: sql, db2

My select query:

```
SELECT CUSTID, EVENT_DTM, CURRENT_LOC, FROM_LOC FROM TABLE
```

Returns the following result:

```
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| CUSTID | EVENT_DTM                  | CURRENT_LOC | FROM_LOC |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 01:33:00.000000 | FRONTDOOR   |          |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 03:50:00.000000 | FRONTDOOR   |          |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 04:32:00.000000 | FOYER       |          |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 05:42:00.000000 | TEMP-ONE    | FOYER    |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 05:58:00.000000 | KITCHEN     | TEMP-ONE |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 10:43:00.000000 | POOL        | KITCHEN  |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 13:01:00.000000 | BEDROOM     | POOL     |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-18 14:00:00.000000 | BEDROOM     |          |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
```

I want to write a select statement such that when CURRENT_LOC = TEMP-ONE and there is a corresponding FROM_LOC = TEMP-ONE that the rows would be combined and the result of the query would be:

```
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| CUSTID | EVENT_DTM                  | CURRENT_LOC | FROM_LOC |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 01:33:00.000000 | FRONTDOOR   |          |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 03:50:00.000000 | FRONTDOOR   |          |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 04:32:00.000000 | FOYER       |          |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 05:58:00.000000 | KITCHEN     | FOYER    |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 10:43:00.000000 | POOL        | KITCHEN  |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-17 13:01:00.000000 | BEDROOM     | POOL     |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
| 1      | 2000-02-18 14:00:00.000000 | BEDROOM     |          |
+--------+----------------------------+-------------+----------+
```

Is there an SQL approach to this problem?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: is there going to be more than one pair of records per custid(ie CURRENT_LOC=TEMP-ONE and FROM_LOC=TEMP-ONE)

Comment: Take a look at recursive SQL and common table expressions. Related links: https://blog.4loeser.net/2018/04/db2-cte-and-connect-by-two-kinds-of.html

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph The number of these records can really vary. There may be no pair of such records or there could be many.

Comment: @data_henrik Will Do!

Comment: Join the table to itself CURRENT_LOC = FROM_LOC

Comment: Trying to understand what your goal is, and a real world explanation might help.  Are you only worried about this logic for the special location TEMP-ONE, because your sample results dont "combine" records when this occurs for other locations, or was that just an oversight.  What is it you want to show exactly in the "combined" record?

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns the result you provided.

```
WITH MYTAB (CUSTID, EVENT_DTM, CURRENT_LOC, FROM_LOC) AS 
(
VALUES
  (1, '2000-02-17 01:33:00.000000', 'FRONTDOOR', '')
, (1, '2000-02-17 03:50:00.000000', 'FRONTDOOR', '')
, (1, '2000-02-17 04:32:00.000000', 'FOYER', '')
, (1, '2000-02-17 05:42:00.000000', 'TEMP-ONE', 'FOYER    ')
, (1, '2000-02-17 05:58:00.000000', 'KITCHEN', 'TEMP-ONE ')
, (1, '2000-02-17 10:43:00.000000', 'POOL', 'KITCHEN  ')
, (1, '2000-02-17 13:01:00.000000', 'BEDROOM', 'POOL     ')
, (1, '2000-02-18 14:00:00.000000', 'BEDROOM', '')
)
SELECT A.CUSTID, A.EVENT_DTM, COALESCE(B.CURRENT_LOC, A.CURRENT_LOC) CURRENT_LOC, A.FROM_LOC
FROM MYTAB A
LEFT JOIN MYTAB B ON B.FROM_LOC = A.CURRENT_LOC AND A.CURRENT_LOC = 'TEMP-ONE'
WHERE A.FROM_LOC <> 'TEMP-ONE';
```